# Run Jenkins' Cygwin script as user

Tags: bash, jenkins, cygwin

I have Jenkins running on Windows, and I have a build that works fine under CygWin `bash` from the CygWin terminal, so I now want to automate it. However, using this script:

```
#!C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
whoami
make
```

The system reports me as `nt authority\system`, not the `ken` that I get when using an interactive shell. Is there an easy way to persuade Jenkins or CygWin to run as me?

Comment: Options: **1.** Change the service account Jenkins is running under **2.** Try using `runas` to exectue the script **3.** Change the script so that it will build regardless of the user building it (you should really try and use this method)

Comment: **3.** is of course the best solution, but my real problem was that I did not have a login shell, so paths weren't being set. I have posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem I was having was not that the shell script was running as the wrong user, but that the shell script was not executing the default `/etc/profile`. So, the solution was simply:

```
#!C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l
whoami
make
```

I was still `nt authority\system`, but now I had the correct environment set up and could run `make` successfully.

Note also that if I create a `/home/system` directory I can add `.bash_profile`, etc, to that directory to further customise the build environment.

Comment: An if someone missed it, it's the '-l' (lowercase L) in the shebang ('#') line that is the difference. This causes the bash to act as a login shell, executing all the necessary setup scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are running jenkins with default installation. You have two options.  First is mentioned in the comment.  Change the "Service account" to be same as yours.

Second option is derived from [best practices](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Best+Practices).  Run the jenkins master on a system with backup etc. Configure slave [node](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) with your account credentials.  Change the project configuration to build on the specific node.

(It is possible to run slave and master on same machine with different credentials - just in case you want to try out things)